# Why is the work done by an expanding ideal gas $\textbf{P}_{ext}\Delta V$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

Consider an ideal gas in a cubical container as our system (only the gas is the system, not the walls of the container). If I understand correctly, if the gas expands at constant pressure $P_{int}$ greater than the ambient pressure $P_{ext}$ (after heating the gas to a certain temperature, the walls of the container, which we'll assume undergoes plastic deformation, can no longer provide a pressure whose sum with the atmospheric pressure counteracts the pressure of the gas, and the gas starts expanding such that as the volume gets scaled by some factor, the temperature gets scaled by that same factor, allowing for expansion at constant pressure $P_{int} > P_{ext}$), the work done by the gas should be

$$
W = \int{\textbf{F}}d\textbf{s} = \int{\frac{\textbf{F}}{A} Ad\textbf{s}} = \int{\textbf{P}_{int}dV} = \textbf{P}_{int} \int{dV} = \textbf{P}_{int}\Delta V .
$$

But this [Khan Academy article](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/internal-energy-sal/a/pressure-volume-work#:%7E:text=Pressure%2Dvolume%20work%3A%20Work%20done,more%20clear%20in%20this%20section!) says that the work done by the expanding (or shrinking) gas is

$$
W = \textbf{P}_{ext}\Delta V,
$$

and, now that I think about it, shouldn't the net work be the difference in works done by the system (gas) and the surroundings, making the correct expression

$$
W = \int{(\textbf{P}_{int} - \textbf{P}_{ext})}dV = (\textbf{P}_{int} - \textbf{P}_{ext}) \Delta V ?
$$

Also, assuming the first expression is true, does this mean that, for an ideal gas, $\textbf{P}V (=NkT=nRT=\textbf{P}\Delta V$ where $V_i=0)$ is the work required to "make room" for the gas (enthalpy minus internal energy) *only if* the greater interior pressure was a constant function of volume and temperature during the expansion from zero volume, and this is what makes work path-dependent and not a state function? (If the interior pressure was a non-constant function of volume dring the expansion from zero volume, work would be given by a line integral, correct?)

Comment: You need to distinguish what the gas is doing work **on**. If it’s the container walls, the pressure imbalance must be accelerating them (and possibly storing strain energy). In this way, more work is done by the gas on the container and surroundings than by the gas and container on the surroundings. This resolves the discrepancy.

Comment: In an rapid irreversible expansion, do you think that the gas satisfies the ideal gas law?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm only considering the gas as the system, so it's doing work on the container and beyond, so $P_{ext}$ is the sum of atmosheric pressure and pressure due to walls of container. If $P_{int}>P_{ext}|$, the walls will expand as you say, but why is the work done by the gas $P_{ext}\Delta V$ and not $P_{int}\Delta V$?

Comment: When you say the internal pressure is constant, do you mean throughout the gas or just where it contacts the walls.

Comment: The constant internal pressure premise seems implausible to me. Assuming elastic (Hookean) deformation of the walls you would need to keep increasing the internal pressure to continue to expand the walls

Comment: @BobD The question states plastic—not elastic—deformation. The simplest plastic model allows quite a bit of strain around the yield point, which I assumed was the reason for that detail.

Comment: @Chemomechanics as I understand it, prior to plastic deformation an object first undergoes elastic deformation.

Comment: @BobD Yes, we can expect some degree of elastic strain energy stored in the container walls when plastic deformation commences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is even possible to deform a material at constant pressure (which I doubt as a material generally undergoes elastic prior to plastic deformation), the work done by the gas on the container is $P_{int}\Delta V$ and the work done by the constant external pressure on the container is $-P_{ext}\Delta V$.

Thus the net work done *on the container* is the sum of two, or $(P_{int}-P_{ext})\Delta V$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes sense. One more thing: if the container itself was part of the surroundings (and system was only the gas), the work done by the surroundings on the gas $P_{surroundings}\Delta V$ would still be less than $P_{system}\Delta V$, since the system is expanding (meaning $P_{system}>P_{surroundings}$), correct?

Comment: @cloud If the gas is the system then the container is the part of the surroundings that interacts directly with the system. Per Newton’s 3rd law the pressure the container exerts on the gas is equal and opposite to the pressure the gas exerts on the container, i.e. $P_{int}$.

Comment: We say the system does positive work of $P_{int}\Delta V$ on  the container since the force  the gas exerts on the container is in the direction of the displacement of the container. When something does positive work on something else it transfers energy to that something else.

Comment: But it is completely analogous to say the container is doing negative work of $-P_{int}\Delta V$ on the gas. When something does negative work on something else it takes energy away from that something else. In the case, the container takes energy away from the gas.

Comment: The same applies when we look at the interaction of the container with its constant pressure environment, say, atmospheric air. Only now the equal and opposite pressure is $P_{ext}$ and is the basis of the work done on/by the container by/on the atmosphere

Comment: The sum of the positive the work done on the container by the gas and the negative work done by the atmosphere on the container is the energy that goes into the deformation of the container.

Comment: *Assuming it is even possible to deform a material at constant pressure (which I doubt as a material generally undergoes elastic prior to plastic deformation)* A [Bingham plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_plastic) satisfies this behavior, for one. A very simple plasticity model in which unlimited strain occurs at any constant stress above the yield stress.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Fine. I suppose we can say the gas container is made of mayonnaise (an example of a Bingham plastic according to the link). Regardless, I already said I am assuming it is a constant pressure process.

Comment: @BobD Ah. So, if I understand correctly, you heat the system (gas) to a certain temp. at which the system is at pressure $P_{int}$ which is the max pressure the container can withstand without deforming. Heating further (assuming container isn't brittle) causes the gas pressure to be greater than $P_{ext}$ (where "ext" are container and outside), making the system expand such that volume and temp. get scaled by the same factor at all times during the process (if we want constant pressure). Then, $W_{net}=P_{system}\Delta V-|P_{ext}\Delta V|$ (where ext = container + atmosphere), correct?

Comment: @cloud That's correct, but I don't understand why you have the absolute value of the external work.  The external work is negative because the direction of the external force on the container is opposite the displacement of the container, which makes the work negative.  So you can drop the absolute value sign.

Comment: @BobD I put it there to emphasize that the net work is a difference of works, as dropping the absolute value would make it a sum: $W_{net}=P_{int}\Delta V + P_{ext}\Delta V.$

Comment: @cloud what I’m saying is $P_{ext}$ is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Word done by the gas on the piston (or deformable wall) is $p_{int} \Delta V$, and work done by the piston on the outside atmosphere of pressure $p_{ext}$ is $p_{ext}\Delta V$.

The difference $(p_{int} - p_{ext})\Delta V$ is the net work done by gas from both sides on the piston.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151821/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-lalinsky-why-is-the-work-done-by-an-expanding-ideal); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.